# I can't understand how enumeration works in C++

Tags: c++

I have just been playing with enumerations in C++ and I still can't understand these two examples:

```
enum Colors {
    WHITE, BLACK, RED
};

Colors colors[3];
colors[0] = WHITE; // it's OK
```

and:

```
enum Colors {
    WHITE, BLACK, RED
};

int colors[3];
colors[0] = WHITE; // it's OK
```

I know that enumeration's elements counts from 0 to n-1 and so they all have values. But why I have to use Colors name of enumeration to declare an array? Why I can't use int instead? Or can I?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `enum` is pretty lax if you are used to enumerated types from other languages

Comment: It is meant for type safety, so that someone would not just pass a random integer value to a function expecting enumeration value without being notified by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The `enum` allows you to use english names for your values between `0` and `n-1`. It's much prettier and understandable for the next developer to have

```
int myColor = Colors::WHITE;
```

than

```
int myColor = 0; // What color is this? I don't know
```

Comment: So what's a difference between Colors myColor; and int myColor?

Comment: @Andrius The difference is that Colors myColor is of type Colors, and int myColor is of type int.

Comment: but they both can hold WHITE from Colors enum, aren't they?

Comment: @Andrius The type is important: imagine you have a function void colorTheRectangle(Color c). If you try to pass a random integer it won't compile. This allows you to enforce the fact that you need a valid color as a parameter for colorTheRectangle

Comment: @Andrius Yes. They both can hold WHITE from Colors enum.

Comment: Technically, I believe you can actually pass a random integer if you cast it to Color

Answer (score 2):

> But why I have to use Colors name of enumeration to declare an array? Why I can't use int instead? Or can I?

You can:

```
enum {
    WHITE,
    BLACK
};

int arr[3];
arr[0] = WHITE;
```

Answer (score 2):

> But why I have to use Colors name of enumeration to declare an array? Why I can't use int instead? Or can I?

Yes you can declare a variable as an `int` instead of declaring it as a `Colors` but the whole point of using an `enum`is that **both** the developer and the compiler can tell that the acceptable values are limited. What's more, the compiler can use this information to issue diagnostics and help the developer avoid mistakes:

```
int color1 = WHITE; // OK
int color1 = 0; // OK, no diagnostic, but what does 0 mean ?
Colors color2 = WHITE; // OK
Colors color2 = 0; // compilation warning or error
```